# Passing an example from "it" block to "let" block in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was watching a codeschool screencast on using RSpec and it had the following lines:

```
describe Game do
  describe '#call' do
    let(:description) do |example|
      example.description
    end

    context 'when the choices are different' do

      subject(:game) { described_class.new }
      it 'rock beats scissors' do |example|
        expect(subject.call('rock', 'scissors')).to eq(description)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't quite see how `example` argument gets into the 'let' block? Is that a Ruby thing or RSpec magic? Thanks.

Comment: RSpec "magic". But it's not very magic, really. The `let` block gets re-called for each spec, possibly in a different context. So it's not very surprising that it has access to data about the test being run.

Comment: @TomLord ohh, I just realised that `let` is different from method declaration in that it gets evaluated lazily. So this must be why? `it` block doesn't really 'pass' the argument, it's just that let is called in the context of `it`?

Comment: @redFur let is evaluated whenever it's called - this could also be in the context of another let block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this line in the `rspec-core` source:](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/f4dc5ef5c6bded2b1ec348e856352b60a3e072e9/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L296)

```
# Simplified version of the code:
def let(name, &block)
  # ...
  if block.arity == 1
    define_method(name) { super(RSpec.current_example, &nil) }
  # ...
end
```

Because `let` is re-evaluated for each test, it can be re-defined to include knowledge of the current test context.

Also worth noting is that [`RSpec.current_example`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/94dc75e23a352c9420b7116eb87ad055e2ce34b9/lib/rspec/core.rb#L122-L124) is **thread-safe**:

```
def self.current_example
  RSpec::Support.thread_local_data[:current_example]
end
```

This means even if you are running parallel tests, each `let` block will always be able to re-evaluate the current example correctly.